# Python time_ns time difference is giving 0 when under 1millis (10^6 ns)

Tags: python, time

Here is a simple code (just for testing purpose) which simply measures time taken to calculate gamma of a number:

```py
from math import gamma
from time import time_ns

start = time_ns()
x = 0.0
for i in range(1, 1564):
    x = gamma(6.31)
taken = time_ns() - start

print("Time taken for calculating gamma is", taken, "ns")
# Time taken for calculating gamma is 1000600 ns

print(x)
```

As soon as I put 1563 as upper limit in range function call, i.e. one less iteration, the output becomes

```py
Time taken for calculating gamma is 0 ns
```

Is there something missing in my code or there is a bug in the library?

Comment: Just because the function is returning times in units of nanoseconds, doesn't mean that the underlying clock hardware has a *resolution* of nanoseconds.

Comment: @jasonharper so what are the ways in which we can precisely measure nanoseconds or microseconds, if possible?

Answer (score 2):

**Measuring the time taken for very small actions is very inaccurate if the number of iterations is too small.** And whether the hardware supports time in microseconds or nanoseconds or not, you also need to account for "overhead" from the machine doing other things.

> Is there something missing in my code or there is a bug in the library?

If the total number of loops is too small and without actual nanosecond resolution, you're getting 0 likely because the entire loop is executing in under 1 millisecond (1000 microseconds, 1000000 ns), so `time_ns() - start` would give 0.

**Your time taken math should include dividing by the number of iterations, so that you get the time per iteration.**

```
loops = 1564
start = time_ns()
for i in range(1, loops+1):
    x = gamma(6.31)

taken = time_ns() - start

print("Time taken for calculating gamma is", taken/loops, "ns")  # divide by # of loops
# 9597.504798464492 ns
```

But I get a more accurate reading if I increase the number of loops to 10,000,000:

```
>>> loops = 10_000_000
>>> start = time_ns()
>>> for i in range(1, loops+1):
...     x = gamma(6.31)
...
>>> taken = time_ns() - start
>>>
>>> print("Time taken for calculating gamma is", taken/loops, "ns")
Time taken for calculating gamma is 389.52228 ns
```

And repeating that a few times gives me an answer between 385 to 395 ns.

There's also the overhead of actually running the loop, which is hard to remove from the math.

Or in IPython:

```
In [6]: %timeit x = gamma(6.31)
371 ns ± 2.11 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

---

You'll get the same problem if you tried to measure the speed of `1 + 1` with too few loops:

```
loops = 10
start = time_ns()
for i in range(1, loops+1):
    x = 1 + 1

taken = time_ns() - start
taken / loops
# gives 0.0
```

Increase that to 100 million and I get 64 ns. But there's "loop overhead", so use [`timeit`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/timeit.html), either to call gamma or from the command line.

```
C:\Users\...>python -m timeit "1+1"
20000000 loops, best of 5: 10.4 nsec per loop

C:\Users\...>python -m timeit -s "from math import gamma" "gamma(6.31)"
1000000 loops, best of 5: 323 nsec per loop
```

Comment: `because the entire loop is executing in under 1 microsecond (1000 ns), so time_ns() - start would give 0.` Not only it gives 0 when operation is under 1μs, as stated in the question's title as well, it gives 0 even if it is under 1ms (1000μs). :(

Comment: Yeah, I meant '1 millisecond' there, since that's likely the minimum resolution of your system clock & OS. And as stated in my answer, you need to increase the number of loops so that the entire operation takes enough time to (a) register a significant time difference and (b) get accurate over many many loops. You'll have the same problem if you try to time `1 + 1` with too few loops.

Comment: I don't think millisecond is minimum time we can measure, in Kotlin i usually do `measureTimeMillis { /* Code */ }` to measure milliseconds and `measureNanoTime { /* Code */ }` to measure nanoseconds and it return it (The curly braces is just a lambda). And I really don't want to measure time of a loop (since I am not benchmarking) I just put it into the question because that's the point (minimium iterations) where I was getting unrelated results, I just wanna see if I can measure a "single" operation.

Comment: See: https://pl.kotl.in/9UguPDC3_ it measures the nano time pretty ok (like usable to log some operation's time taken).